# Calling ForgeApp.event with second not null parameter

Tags: trigger.io

I want to call ForgeApp.event with second not null parameter
and used this method in java side (for String parameter message)

```
ForgeApp.event("sdk.showMessage", new JsonPrimitive(message));
```

How can I process this method from js side?

There is no description in [trigger.io documentation](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/javascript_events.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger a native event in Javascript you will need to add a method to your  module/javascript/module.js file that will register a Javascript event handler with the native code:

For example,

```
forge.your_module_name = {
    "onEventName": {
        "addListener": function (success) {
            forge.internal.addEventListener("your_module_name.EventName", success);
        }
    }
};
```

Now, in your app you can add an event listener with:

```
forge.your_module_name.onEventName.addListener(function () {
    alert("EventName was fired");
});
```